# Force "open in..." selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uidocumentinteraction

My code at the moment looks like this:

```
- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL:(NSURL *)fileURL
                                           usingDelegate:(id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>)         interactionDelegate {

    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController =
    [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
    interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;

    [interactionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];

    return interactionController;
```

}

```
- (void)showOptionsMenu
{
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"2bm.key"];
    docController = [self setupControllerWithURL:fileURL
                                   usingDelegate:self];
}

- (IBAction)KeynoteButton:(id)sender {

     [self showOptionsMenu];
}
```

This generates an open in keynote bubble at the top left of the screen. Is it possible for me to move where this bubble appears? Or even better can I force a touch event on this bubble so the user does not have a choice, keynote opens automatically? I cannot use an URL reference scheme for this as keynote does not support this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify where the popover appears by specifying the proper location in the `presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:` method. Right now you specify `CGRectZero`. Pass in the proper `CGRect` that indicates where you want it to appear.

You can't force a specific app. Many users will have several apps that can open the given file. Let the user choose where it is to go.